# Connecting to asana using webrequests

Tags: asana

I'm a hobbiest VB developer and have been tinkering with desktop apps for a while now. Hoever I'm a total noob when it comes to web development and things called 'Restful' API's (Is it supposed to make you calm?)

I have tried to follow the logic behind some of the posts on getting task information from asana, but honestly, I don't have the time to study and figure out Ruby on Rails just so I can write the backend for a webpage (which I wouldn't know what to do with) to connect to asana to get some information back.

I'm looking for anyone that can guide me through the following steps (I really don't mind reading ***focused*** articles from the web so feel free to recommend them, but up till this point I have read too much to recall here, nothing of which points me a helpful direction)

When creating a new application I want to:

- Connect to a specific asana task
- Get specific information on the task (such as the header / heading / comments)

I have tried the following:
Create an app with a webrequest
Read examples on the asana API (restful...but not for me :)), rubygems, JSON, PHP etc, but this is impractical as it is simply to much information...
So I would really like to know and tremendously appreciate it if there is a VB developer (or c#) that can post a simple sample of how to achieve this

Once I get a single request working, I can do the rest. I just need to know *how / where* to start

Your advice is much appreciated

This is the code i'm using at the moment:

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim response As String = GetResponse("https://app.asana.com/0/taskIDhere")
        MsgBox(response)
 End Sub

Public Function GetResponse(uri As String, Optional data As String = "", Optional method As String = "GET") As String
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(uri)

        ' create request
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(uri), HttpWebRequest)
        request.PreAuthenticate = True
        request.Method = method
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

        ' log in
        Dim authInfo As String = API_KEY & ":" & ""
        ' blank password
        authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.[Default].GetBytes(authInfo))
        request.Headers("Authorization") = "Basic " & authInfo

        ' send data
        If data <> "" Then
            Dim paramBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data)
            request.ContentLength = paramBytes.Length
            Dim reqStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
            reqStream.Write(paramBytes, 0, paramBytes.Length)
            reqStream.Close()
        End If

        ' get response
        Try
            Dim response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
            Return New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()
        Catch ex As WebException
            Dim response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(ex.Response, HttpWebResponse)
            Throw New Exception((uri & " caused a " & CInt(response.StatusCode) & " error." & vbLf) + response.StatusDescription)
        End Try
    End Function
```

But this just returns the content of the webpage

Comment: Okay it seems the above code was correct. My interpretation of the feedback was what was incorrect.

Now I just need to figure out how to get the task Id's :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I work at Asana.) Have you looked at any of the [Asana API documentation](http://developer.asana.com/documentation/)? Your main problem at the moment is that you're accessing the wrong URL. All API requests start with:

`https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/`

And then depending on what you want to do, you may add things to the path. Most services have different URLs for their web-based access and their API access, as they often work very differently.

For an easy GET request, try adding `users/me` to the path above. Your authentication code looks correct to me so I suspect this will work with the code you have.

Comment: Hi thanks I saw that and have since been able to connect nicely! However when I try to create tasks using the format https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/workspaces/workspaceid/tasks -d "name=this is a new task" I get an error.. see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16609415/url-returns-error